# Selected Index of UI Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS programming 
I would like to Save the Selected `Cell (cell.detailTextLabel.text)` to another `Textfield` outside of table view in the same `viewController` .
Can anyone suggest me how?

Comment: great..what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this delegate method of the table view,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    selectedLabelName = cell.textLabel.text;
}
```

declare variable name **selectedLabelName** in your viewcontroller